# adding a data frame at the end of every last row of a group in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame df which looks like this:

df

```
mut   pi   pos  Pass
A     1   1010  010
G     1   1010  010
T     1   2020  020
T     1   2020  020
C     1   2020  020
A     1   5010  030
G     1   5010  040
G     1   5010  040
G     1   5010  040
C     1   5010  040
```

I want to create a new data frame and insert it at the and of the last value of each unique groups in the Pass column:

```
vec <- c("N",0,3333,"SEP")
df_insert<-as.data.frame(t(replicate(2, vec)))
```

Desired output:

```
mut   pi   pos  Pass
A     1   1010  010
G     1   1010  010
N     0   3333  SEP
N     0   3333  SEP
T     1   2020  020
T     1   2020  020
C     1   2020  020
N     0   3333  SEP
N     0   3333  SEP
A     1   5010  030
N     0   3333  SEP
N     0   3333  SEP
G     1   5010  040
G     1   5010  040
G     1   5010  040
C     1   5010  040
N     0   3333  SEP
N     0   3333  SEP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split()` your `df` on the `Pass` column, then `rbind()` each chunk together with `insert_df`, and finally `rbind()` the whole thing together:

```r
df_split  <- split(df, df$Pass)
insert_list  <- replicate(
    length(df_split), 
    setNames(df_insert, names(df)),
    simplify = FALSE
)

do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, df_split, insert_list))

#        mut pi  pos Pass
# 010.1    A  1 1010  010
# 010.2    G  1 1010  010
# 010.3    N  0 3333  SEP
# 010.4    N  0 3333  SEP
# 020.3    T  1 2020  020
# 020.4    T  1 2020  020
# 020.5    C  1 2020  020
# 020.1    N  0 3333  SEP
# 020.2    N  0 3333  SEP
# 030.6    A  1 5010  030
# 030.1    N  0 3333  SEP
# 030.2    N  0 3333  SEP
# 040.7    G  1 5010  040
# 040.8    G  1 5010  040
# 040.9    G  1 5010  040
# 040.10   C  1 5010  040
# 040.1    N  0 3333  SEP
# 040.2    N  0 3333  SEP

all(
    do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, df_split, insert_list)) == desired_output
) # TRUE
```

Or if you prefer you can do it in a one-liner with `lapply()`:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Pass), \(d) rbind(d, setNames(df_insert, names(df)))))
# same output
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` approach using `tibble::add_rows()` and `purr::map_dfr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  group_split(pos, Pass) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(~ .x %>% tibble::add_row(df_insert))
```

output:

```
#    mut   pi    pos   Pass 
#    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#  1 A     1     1010  10   
#  2 G     1     1010  10   
#  3 N     0     3333  SEP  
#  4 N     0     3333  SEP  
#  5 T     1     2020  20   
#  6 T     1     2020  20   
#  7 C     1     2020  20   
#  8 N     0     3333  SEP  
#  9 N     0     3333  SEP  
# 10 A     1     5010  30   
# 11 N     0     3333  SEP  
# 12 N     0     3333  SEP  
# 13 G     1     5010  40   
# 14 G     1     5010  40   
# 15 G     1     5010  40   
# 16 C     1     5010  40   
# 17 N     0     3333  SEP  
# 18 N     0     3333  SEP
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an *incredibly* janky way of doing it, using `across()` and `separate_longer_delim()`. Sam or JP's ways are better, I just wanted to see if it could be done this way (turns out, the answer is yes!):

```
df |>
 mutate(r = row_number(), g = cumsum(Pass != lag(Pass, default = first(Pass))),
        across(-c(r, g), ~ ifelse(g == lead(g, default = first(g)), ., paste(rep(vec[which(colnames(df) == cur_column())], 2), collapse = "|") |> paste0(.,"|", ... = _)))) |>
        separate_longer_delim(-c(r, g), "|") |> 
        select(-g, -r)
```

Output:

```
   mut pi  pos Pass
1    A  1 1010   10
2    G  1 1010   10
3    N  0 3333  SEP
4    N  0 3333  SEP
5    T  1 2020   20
6    T  1 2020   20
7    C  1 2020   20
8    N  0 3333  SEP
9    N  0 3333  SEP
10   A  1 5010   30
11   N  0 3333  SEP
12   N  0 3333  SEP
13   G  1 5010   40
14   G  1 5010   40
15   G  1 5010   40
16   C  1 5010   40
17   N  0 3333  SEP
18   N  0 3333  SEP
```