# How to add blank rows

Tags: r, dplyr

In dataframe  `raw_df` , how to add blank rows `A_BLANK` `B_BLANK` ? Result as `wished_df`. Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
raw_df <- data.frame(category=c('A','A','B','B','C'),
                        value=c(1:5),
                        amount=c(1:5))

wished_df <- data.frame(category=c('A','A','A_BLANK','B','B','B_BLANK','C'),
                        value =c(1,2,NA,3,4,'NA',5),
                        amount =c(1,2,NA,3,4,'NA',5))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding a data frame at the end of every last row of a group in another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050304/adding-a-data-frame-at-the-end-of-every-last-row-of-a-group-in-another-data-fram)

Comment: hmm is C meant to have a C_BLANK category too?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403282/add-row-in-each-group-using-dplyr-and-add-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jpsmith's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77050687/4145280) to a very similar question can be used, with a few adjustments:

```
bad <- c('C_BLANK') # replace with whatever the names are in the real data

raw_df |>
  group_split(category) |>
  map_dfr(~ .x |> add_row(category = paste0(.x$category[1], '_BLANK'), value = NA, amount = NA)) |>
  filter(!category %in% bad)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  category value amount
  <chr>    <int>  <int>
1 A            1      1
2 A            2      2
3 A_BLANK     NA     NA
4 B            3      3
5 B            4      4
6 B_BLANK     NA     NA
7 C            5      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just merge it with `all = TRUE`

```
wished_df <- merge(
  raw_df,
  data.frame(category = paste(unique(raw_df$category), "BLANK", sep = "_")),
  all = TRUE
)

head(wished_df, -1) # remove the "C_BLANK" row

#   category value amount
# 1        A     1      1
# 2        A     2      2
# 3  A_BLANK    NA     NA
# 4        B     3      3
# 5        B     4      4
# 6  B_BLANK    NA     NA
# 7        C     5      5
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use rbind

```
rbind(raw_df, NA)
```

Or, if you want category names:

```
df <-data.frame(category = "A", value = NA, amount=NA)
bind_rows(raw_df, df)
```

Comment: I don't think this gives the desired output?